# How do I change the 'created' stamp timezone dynamically in CakePHP

Tags: cakephp, timestamp

I can change the PHP time zone, but the database is still stamped with the server time. How can I change this so it shows the correct time zone? It's dynamic based on which item a user is loaded in to - so I need to be able to change at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

For CakePHP 3.x, please open `config/bootstrap.php` file. Make search for `date_default_timezone_set`. Set it as you want. I set it as `date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Dhaka');` for my time zone. You can get your time zone from http://php.net/manual/en/timezones.php

If it's not working, please also open `config/app.php` file. Make search for `timezone`. In your `Datasources` connection set `'timezone'=>'Asia/Dhaka'`